# Calculate AUC for the ROC in R

Tags: r

I'm quite new to R and I was wondering how can i achieve following thing: I have two vectors (of the same length), one contains sensitivity (tpr) values and the other corresponding 1-specificity (fpr) values. I would like to create a ROC curve and calculate area under curve. Is there some simple way of doing that? I tried to use auc function from the AUC package, but when using auc(tpr, fpr) i get an error: Error in auc(tpr, fpr) : object 'ans' not found.

Comment: If you can start from the raw data (vector with predicted probabilities and vector with outcomes), there are packages that do the whole thing for you, from plotting the ROC curve to computing AUC. For instance, `pROC`.

Comment: Show the relevant part of your code.

Comment: I have a vector of outcomes which contains TPR and FPR values observed for a different version of algorithm. I don't have predicted probabilities, that's why i find it difficult to use suggested packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have TPR and FPR you can calculate the area under the curve using a trapezoidal approximation. This can be calculated in R using the trapz function.

By plotting TPR vs FPR you will be able to visualise the curve. Perhaps start with this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i calculated the area using: AUC <- trapz(tpr,fpr) as you suggested.

Comment: no problem, please feel free to accept the answer if you feel its satisfactory :) ALSO please note that this may not be the best approximation for the area under the curve but will give you something to work with.